# Using Graphviz's dot or neato to layout clusters

Tags: graphviz, dot, neato

I'm trying to draw a deployment diagram of services and servers in our enterprise using dot. For the first iteration, I used neato to draw each service as a box and [Prevent overlapping records using graphviz and neato](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039785/need-help-with-overlapping-records-using-graphviz-and-neato) , plus allowing splines, allowed me to get a decent layout with the edges as dependencies.

Now I need to place physical servers inside each of these boxes. First I made each service a subgraph with a name beginning with *cluster* and then placed the nodes representing the physical servers inside each box. Again, with the help of [GraphViz - How to connect subgraphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012036/graphviz-how-to-connect-subgraphs) I faked out the edges to connect the clusters rather than the nodes. The problem is, that only works in dot. When I use neato to do the layout, it doesn't understand the edges are between clusters, so it moves only the node of the cluster I used to anchor the edge. The result is the cluster boxes are enormous and overlapping.

I hope that makes sense. Is there any way to force neato to keep the nodes in a cluster grouped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I rethought what I was doing, and instead of using a subgraph for each service with subnodes for each server, I used a [*record*](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#record) format instead. Each node now looks like

```
+------------------------------+
|         Service name         |
+------------------------------+
| server1 | server2 | server 3 |
+------------------------------+
```

and it's *much* easier to lay those out :)

Comment: Here is a link to the docs for records: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#record

Comment: Thanks, that's a worthwhile addition to this answer in case anyone else finds this :)

Comment: The HTML-like labels are much more flexible than records btw.

Comment: I have incorporated the reference into your answer, I hope that is okay with you.