# Is there a way to draw cluster with neato?

Tags: graphviz, neato

I have a graph that is best presented with neato. However it seems that neato doesn't support cluster? Here is a test code and its graphic:

```
graph G {
    subgraph clusterA{
    1;
    2;
    3;
    }
    
}
```

[image]

<sub>I also ask this on [GraphViz forum](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/why-does-neato-not-support-cluster/680?u=ooker)</sub>

Comment: There does not seem to be any definitive documentation, but the effective answer is no.  Neato does not usefully support clusters.

Comment: @sroush why is that?

Comment: I am just a groupie, you'll have to ask the developers (https://forum.graphviz.org/)  (I'd guess that the cluster concept does not match well with the neato algorithm)  You might also request this feature (https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues)

Comment: You may be interested that neato supports records, see [*Using Graphviz's dot or neato to layout clusters*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5176004/2932052) for more.