# How to deal with densely connected graphs with neato

Tags: graphviz, neato

I have the following dot/neato file...

```
graph G
{

  node [color=Red]

  r01
  r02

  r03

  r04
  r05

  r06
  r07
  r08
  r09

  r10
  r11

  node [color=Blue]

  p01
  p02

  p03

  p04
  p05
  p06

  p07
  p08
  p09
  p10
  p11

  p12
  p13

  r01 -- r02
  r01 -- p01
  r01 -- p02
  r02 -- p01
  r02 -- p02
  p01 -- p02

  r03 -- p03

  r04 -- r05
  r04 -- p04
  r04 -- p05
  r04 -- p06
  r05 -- p04
  r05 -- p06
  p04 -- p05
  p04 -- p06

  r06 -- r07
  r06 -- r08
  r06 -- r09
  r06 -- p07
  r06 -- p08
  r06 -- p09
  r06 -- p10
  r06 -- p11
  r07 -- r08
  r07 -- r09
  r07 -- p07
  r07 -- p08
  r07 -- p09
  r07 -- p10
  r07 -- p11
  r08 -- r09
  r08 -- p07
  r08 -- p08
  r08 -- p09
  r08 -- p10
  r08 -- p11
  r09 -- p07
  r09 -- p08
  r09 -- p09
  r09 -- p10
  r09 -- p11
  p07 -- p08
  p07 -- p09
  p07 -- p10
  p07 -- p11
  p08 -- p09
  p08 -- p10
  p08 -- p11
  p09 -- p10
  p09 -- p11
  p10 -- p11

  r10 -- r11
  r10 -- p12
  r10 -- p13
  r11 -- p12
  r11 -- p13
  p12 -- p13
}
```

...from which I create [this graphic](http://postimage.org/image/2f9jubi9w/) using `neato`.

```
neato -Tpng -o graph-g.png graph-g.txt
```

Overall, `neato` does a decent job, but the largest connected component in the graph looks pretty ridiculous. What can I do to make this look better? My criteria are that no nodes should overlap and there should be enough distance between connected nodes so that you can see a bit of the edge between them.

Comment: Just found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039785/need-help-with-overlapping-records-using-graphviz-and-neato), so my question looks like a duplicate. However, I like the answers to this thread better!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you add the following to the top of your graph:

```
overlap=false;
splines=true;
```

The result is:

[image: graphviz output no overlap with splines]

Not only the nodes do not overlap anymore, but also the edges are routed around the nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Graphviz has an `overlap` attribute (look for it [here](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/schema/attributes.xml)) that can sometimes be applied successfully.

When I insert `overlap = false` above your first `node` attribute the following image is the result.

[image: Graph using overlap = false]

When I instead insert `overlap = scalexy` in the same location, I get the following.

[image: Graph using overlap = scalexy]

Unfortunately, you still have edges passing through node `p11`. Hopefully, a way to address that can also be found.

You can see an example of `overlap = false` gone bad near the bottom of this [page](http://www.burlaca.com/2009/02/html2gdl-graphviz/).